# Method to prove authenticity of download files in hindsight

Tags: authentication, web, resources, integrity

I'm looking for a tool or method to prove the authenticity of resources download from the web and stored locally. To be clear: I don't mean the SHA or MD5 checksums to verify a downloaded file. What I need is a way to download and store a web resource in such a way that I can later prove that said resource indeed originated from that web server.

In particular for the following scenario: A website published an article about a client. He would like to sue for defamation of character. I need a way to store the article without them having the possibility of simply removing it and denying they ever published it. So preferably this would be a tool that is backed by publications making it credible in court.

I have thought about storing the TLS certificate, keys and the encrypted data. That would rely on the root CA, but I think that would in itself not be a problem. I could do this using a custom program and a library like OpenSSL, but I think this is such a common problem, there probably is a relatively standard tool for it. Also, I am not entirely sure to what extent this would constitute reliable evidence. And can someone point to publications that would back this method?

Maybe I am using the wrong search terms, but everything I find is about aforementioned SHA or MD5 checksums. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need something like signature with timestamp. Yes?
You not only need checksum from document (article, text value, whatever) but also proof that this article really existed in time.
When using digital signature you can store such `timestamp` in 3rd party certified providers. You sign document and send checksum to 3rd party provider. Later you can ask provider to verify that this exact document is valid & was indeed created at given time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping

As this can cost (fee for provider to store the timestamps) you can create checksums from many documents (like take all documents from one hour), store all of them in a single file, create checksum from that file and sign it with timestamp. This way you create one timestamp for documents batch, not for each document.